# MYSQL find name on dirty fullname

Tags: mysql

How can I find name with this string.

Database FullName: "John , Doe"

in this example the Full name is dirty as you can see there is space and comma between the name

I need to use this string: "John Doe" or "Doe John" to find "John , Doe" in the database.

Table:

```
id Fullname
1  John , Doe
```

SQL QUERY: tried using this code but no luck.

```
SELECT *
FROM Name
WHERE `FullName` LIKE '%John Doe%'
```

Or

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Name
 WHERE `FullName` LIKE '%Doe John%'
```

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM \`Name\` WHERE FullName LIKE '%John%Doe%';`?

Comment: Divide user input to separate words then search the column against each word and count the amount of successes per row.

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Name
WHERE IF(`FullName` LIKE '%John%',1,0)=1
AND IF(`FullName` LIKE '%Doe%',1,0)=1;
```

Here's a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88445148624b715395b5fc8f48cd1956